Comparing two files with more than 200 lines fails
I am comparing two text files but the result that is returned in certain cases is wrong, I have verified that it happens when the file exceeds 200 lines and only in some cases.
In the comparison I only get the positive results from file2.
Input
These are the two text files that I compare.
I share them with Google drive links because they are very long:

file1
file2

Output
What it returns is:
different

EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO,El Bosque Encantado,"PRECIO
12,00�"

When it should return:
different

CIBELES DE CINE,Galer�a de Cristal de CentroCentro,"PRECIO
7,00�"

By testing I have seen that If I deleted an intro from the end of the files and leave them at 200 lines, it does it well but if I go over 200 lines it does it wrong.
Code
# BOOKSTORES
import difflib
import sys

# WE LOOK FOR THE DIFFERENCES AND PRINT THEM.
with open('file1.txt', encoding='utf8') as file_1, open('file2.txt', encoding='utf8') as file_2:
    diff = difflib.Differ()
    result = diff.compare(file_1.readlines(), file_2.readlines())
    result = [line for line in result if line.startswith(("+ "))]

    print(''.join(result))

sys.exit(1)

What am I doing wrong? Can it be done in another way that makes it correct?

Why is there no line starting with + in the output of your program?

Why would there be?

Because the program should print ''.join(result) where result = [line for line in result if line.startswith(("+ "))]. It literally should only print lines starting with +.

I get exactly the result you expect (ofc with +  at the start of the output lines)?

Why did you remove the text from "What it returns" and "What it should return"?

Please don't vandalize your question. You should roll back to the prior version.

Looking at the files you sent, the difference between these two files is in the order of CIBELES DE CINE... and EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO.... The differ algorithm is Gestalt pattern matching which tries to the longest matching sub-strings in between 2 strings. The library, looking through both texts finds the first difference at start of CIBELES DE CINE in file1 and EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO in file 2.
The difference is best visualized using the output of git diff --no-index file1.txt file2.txt:
diff --git a/file1.txt b/file2.txt
index 3df93b6..69dd17e 100644
--- a/file1.txt
+++ b/file2.txt
@@ -5,10 +5,10 @@ CALLAS EN CONCIERTO,Gran Teatro CaixaBank Príncipe Pío,"PRECIO
 18,00€"
 AUTOCINE MADRID,Autocine Madrid,"PRECIO
 9,90€"
-EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO,El Bosque Encantado,"PRECIO
-12,00€"
 CIBELES DE CINE,Galería de Cristal de CentroCentro,"PRECIO
 7,00€"
+EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO,El Bosque Encantado,"PRECIO
+12,00€"^M
 JAPÓN ARTE Y MANGA,COAM - Colegio Oficial Arquitectos de Madrid,"PRECIO
 11,50€"
 "FIRST DATE, EL MUSICAL",Gran Teatro CaixaBank Príncipe Pío,"PRECIO

One of the shortest ways to transform file1 to file2 is to first remove 2 lines from file1 and then add them 2 lines later. You are only printing the addition of lines, so your output is as described above.
If on the other hand you would compare file2 to file1, the output would be:
diff --git a/file2.txt b/file1.txt
index 69dd17e..3df93b6 100644
--- a/file2.txt
+++ b/file1.txt
@@ -5,10 +5,10 @@ CALLAS EN CONCIERTO,Gran Teatro CaixaBank Príncipe Pío,"PRECIO
 18,00€"
 AUTOCINE MADRID,Autocine Madrid,"PRECIO
 9,90€"
-CIBELES DE CINE,Galería de Cristal de CentroCentro,"PRECIO
-7,00€"
 EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO,El Bosque Encantado,"PRECIO
 12,00€"
+CIBELES DE CINE,Galería de Cristal de CentroCentro,"PRECIO
+7,00€"^M
 JAPÓN ARTE Y MANGA,COAM - Colegio Oficial Arquitectos de Madrid,"PRECIO
 11,50€"
 "FIRST DATE, EL MUSICAL",Gran Teatro CaixaBank Príncipe Pío,"PRECIO

Where the first added lines would be the ones you requested above.

Wow, didn't know about the influence of the Gestalt approach for pattern-matching, particularly string-comparison, or that computer-game programmer John W. Ratclif invented it in 1983.

TL;DR: file1 has "EL BOSQUE", file2 has "CIBELES" as first difference - so the order of comparison changes the output.

I would like to explain the basic mechanics, importance of order and output visualization (including change symbols) when doing textual line-by-line comparisons or diffs.
Understanding these diff-basics can explain the different outputs here.
Pre-tests (word count)
First some statistics about the file-dimensions to spot major differences early.
To see lines, words and characters we can use the Unix/Linux command word-count wc for both text-files:
wc file1.txt file2.txt

prints
  199   763  6528 file1.txt
  199   763  6528 file2.txt
  398  1526 13056 total

We quickly see that quantity-wise each file has the same: 199 lines, with 763 words and 6528. Maybe the only difference is the structure or order of content (like moved lines or swapped words).
Basics of diff
The Unix/Linux command diff from GNU Diffutils (similar to version-control's git diff or Python's difflib) can also show differences between two files:
diff -c file1.txt file2.txt

with the option -c for "copied context" prints the added (+) or deleted (-) lines within their context (the lines before and after, here line range from 5 to 14).
*** file1.txt   2024-07-25 19:23:18.157369933 +0200
--- file2.txt   2024-07-25 19:23:53.821991650 +0200
***************
*** 5,14 ****
  18,00€"
  AUTOCINE MADRID,Autocine Madrid,"PRECIO
  9,90€"
- EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO,El Bosque Encantado,"PRECIO
- 12,00€"
  CIBELES DE CINE,Galería de Cristal de CentroCentro,"PRECIO
  7,00€"
  JAPÓN ARTE Y MANGA,COAM - Colegio Oficial Arquitectos de Madrid,"PRECIO
  11,50€"
  "FIRST DATE, EL MUSICAL",Gran Teatro CaixaBank Príncipe Pío,"PRECIO
--- 5,14 ----
  18,00€"
  AUTOCINE MADRID,Autocine Madrid,"PRECIO
  9,90€"
  CIBELES DE CINE,Galería de Cristal de CentroCentro,"PRECIO
  7,00€"
+ EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO,El Bosque Encantado,"PRECIO
+ 12,00€"
  JAPÓN ARTE Y MANGA,COAM - Colegio Oficial Arquitectos de Madrid,"PRECIO
  11,50€"
  "FIRST DATE, EL MUSICAL",Gran Teatro CaixaBank Príncipe Pío,"PRECIO

Here it shows what the difference is:

2 lines with identical content have different position in both files

This change in position - a move - is like applying two steps: (1) delete those lines from file1 and (2) add them somewhere else further down, to get a different structure like file2:

in file1 they are on line 8,9 (deleted)
in file2 they are on line 10,11 (added)

⚠️ NOTE: The order of file arguments will change the diff output !
Re-order the diff
The diff command compares two files diff FILE1 FILE2, where:

FILE1: is <to-file> or <file-to-edit> or <actual> , compared with
FILE2: is <from-file> or <file-as-reference> or <previous>

So, re-ordered the command diff -c file2.txt file1.txt shows the transformation steps reversed - with the other lines ("CIBELES") because now they differ first:
*** file2.txt   2024-07-25 19:23:53.821991650 +0200
--- file1.txt   2024-07-25 19:23:18.157369933 +0200
***************
*** 5,14 ****
  18,00€"
  AUTOCINE MADRID,Autocine Madrid,"PRECIO
  9,90€"
- CIBELES DE CINE,Galería de Cristal de CentroCentro,"PRECIO
- 7,00€"
  EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO,El Bosque Encantado,"PRECIO
  12,00€"
  JAPÓN ARTE Y MANGA,COAM - Colegio Oficial Arquitectos de Madrid,"PRECIO
  11,50€"
  "FIRST DATE, EL MUSICAL",Gran Teatro CaixaBank Príncipe Pío,"PRECIO
--- 5,14 ----
  18,00€"
  AUTOCINE MADRID,Autocine Madrid,"PRECIO
  9,90€"
  EL BOSQUE ENCANTADO,El Bosque Encantado,"PRECIO
  12,00€"
+ CIBELES DE CINE,Galería de Cristal de CentroCentro,"PRECIO
+ 7,00€"
  JAPÓN ARTE Y MANGA,COAM - Colegio Oficial Arquitectos de Madrid,"PRECIO
  11,50€"
  "FIRST DATE, EL MUSICAL",Gran Teatro CaixaBank Príncipe Pío,"PRECIO

See also

How to Use the Diff Command in Linux [Output Explained]
WC Command Examples: Count Number of Lines, Words & Characters
linux - Understanding of diff output - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange
Comparing two .txt files using difflib in Python

